# Unable to cast object of type System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some problem on getting the value of a specific row of the datagrid when I click the button.
Does anyone know if there is another way of getting the value of the datagrid when button is clicked.

My XAML Datagrid Code:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="coursesList" Margin="20" 
              AlternationCount="2" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" 
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="#00000000" 
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFD6D6D6" 
              AlternatingRowBackground="#FFE2E2E2" 
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
              CanUserAddRows="False">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="40" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path='id'}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="100" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path='courseCode'}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descriptive Title" Width="*" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path='descriptiveTitle'}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lec" Width="50" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path='lec'}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lab" Width="50" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path='lab'}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Units" Width="61" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path='units'}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Instructor" Width="*" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path='instructor'}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="editCourseBtn" Content="Edit" Click="editCourseBtn_Click"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

My C# code:

```
       private void editCourseBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    
       {
        
           try
       
       {
         
            DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)((Button)e.Source).DataContext;

            string id = dataRowView[0].ToString();
            string courseCode = dataRowView[1].ToString();
            string descriptiveTitle = dataRowView[2].ToString();
            string lec = dataRowView[3].ToString();
            string lab = dataRowView[4].ToString();
            string units = dataRowView[5].ToString();
            string instructor = dataRowView[6].ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: *of a specific row* - which row?

Comment: the same row of the button that I clicked in the Edit Column

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `sender`argument instead of `e.Source`:

```
DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)((Button)sender).DataContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a Class or a Model that corresponds the value of the datagrid and use this method instead:

Course edtCourse = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as Course;

course refers to the class course.

```
 private void editCourseBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Course edtCourse = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as Course;

            int id = edtCourse.id;
            string courseCode = edtCourse.courseCode;
            string descriptiveTitle = edtCourse.descriptiveTitle;
            int lec = edtCourse.lec;
            int lab = edtCourse.lab;
            int units = edtCourse.units;
            string instructor = edtCourse.instructor;

            EditCourse edtCourseWindow = new EditCourse();
            edtCourseWindow.courseCoudeTxtBox.Text = courseCode;
            edtCourseWindow.descriptiveTitleTxtBox.Text = descriptiveTitle;
            edtCourseWindow.lecTxtBox.Text = lec.ToString();
            edtCourseWindow.labTxtBox.Text = lab.ToString();
            edtCourseWindow.unitsTxtBox.Text = units.ToString();
            edtCourseWindow.instructorTxtBox.Text = instructor;
            edtCourseWindow.idParameter.Text = id.ToString();
            edtCourseWindow.ShowDialog();
            fetchCourses();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```